# Derivative to ln(K(t)) in the RBC model

Tags: elasticity-of-substitution

In the calculation of the equation of motion for capital in the RBC model, I came across this equation:

[image]

Can someone explain what are the mathematical steps in between? I don't see how exactly the derivative to ln(K(t)) gets us an almost elasticity-like equation.

Would be thankful for any leads. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the formula of the elasticity of substitution of $K_{t+1}$ with respect to $K_t$ expressed differently. Notice that the differential of the function $\ln K_{t+1}$ is $d\ln K_{t+1}=\frac{1}{K_{t+1}}\frac{d K_{t+1}}{d K_{t+1}}d K_{t+1}$ (see [section 12.9](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1292074612) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticity_of_substitution#Definition)), then $d\ln K_{t+1}=\frac{d K_{t+1}}{K_{t+1}}$. Hence, using the same operation with $\ln K_{t}$ and combining we get the elasticity of substitution of $K_{t+1}$ with respect to $K_t$:

$$
\frac{d\ln K_{t+1}}{d\ln K_{t}}=\frac{d K_{t+1}}{d K_{t}}\frac{K_{t}}{K_{t+1}}.
$$

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful for understanding the quick logic behind it :)